# Executing getSunlightTimes function in R with data frame?

Tags: r, spatial

I am hoping that you can support me with the use of the getSunlightTimes function. I have a pixel level data frame ("latlon2") with latitude ("lat"), longitude ("lon"), and one date ("date") in format YYYY-MM-DD. The data covers the continental US, and I also have a state code variable in the data frame.

To obtain the `date` variable as a date class variable, I executed:

```
latlon2$date=as.Date(latlon2$d2003s)
```

I am trying to use the `getSunlightTimes` to identify the time of sunrise and sunset for each pixel on the designated date. However, I am having a hard time getting the function to work. There is not a lot of information on this command beyond R's help guides, so I am hoping some of you have worked with it and can offer your suggestions based on my approach so far.

First I tried using the `getSunlightTimes` function designating each latitude/longitude/date column in my data frame

```
sunrise2003CET=getSunlightTimes(date="latlon2$date", lat="latlon2$lat", lon="latlon2$lon", tz="CET", keep = c("sunrise", "sunset"))
```

R returns the error:

> Error in getSunlightTimes(date = "latlon2$date2", lat = "latlon2$lat",
>   :    date must to be a Date object (class Date)

What's frustrating about this is that when I look at class(latlon2$date) R verifies that the column is a "Date" class!

Next, I tried designating the data frame only:

```
sunrise2003CET=getSunlightTimes(data="latlon2", tz="CET", keep = c("sunrise", "sunset"))
```

R returns the error:

> Error in .buildData(date = date, lat = lat, lon = lon, data = data) : 
>   all(c("date", "lat", "lon") %in% colnames(data)) is not TRUE

This seems odd because I named the columns in the dataframe "date", "lat", "lon", but perhaps the error is due to the fact that there are other variables in the data frame (such as state code).

I am trying to perform this task for several dates across 15 years (and four time zones), so any suggestions on how to get this running, and also running efficiently, are much appreciated!

Thank you so much!

Colette

Comment: Just to clarify, there was a typo in my original post. The first command I tried was sunrise2003CET=getSunlightTimes(date="latlon2$date", lat="latlon2$lat", lon="latlon2$lon", tz="CET", keep = c("sunrise", "sunset"))

Comment: I edited that change into your question.  Someone else edited it for formatting, but they don't get any credit for the edit.  Oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the quotes.  When you write

```
sunrise2003CET=getSunlightTimes(date="latlon2$date", 
                                lat="latlon2$lat",
                                lon="latlon2$lon", 
                                tz="CET", 
                                keep = c("sunrise", "sunset"))
```

you shouldn't put the expressions for the `date`, `lat` and `lon` arguments in quotes, because then R will see them as strings. (You could try `class("latlon2$date")` to see this.) Just write it as

```
sunrise2003CET=getSunlightTimes(date=latlon2$date, 
                                lat=latlon2$lat,
                                lon=latlon2$lon, 
                                tz="CET", 
                                keep = c("sunrise", "sunset"))
```